# Google App Script: Refreshing Addons with Triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

I have created an add-on for Google Sheets.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger('checksheetchange')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onChange()
  .create()

function checksheetchange(){
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
var cardHeader = CardService.newCardHeader();
var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())
cardHeader.setTitle(
  '<font color="#1257e0">File upload error!</font>'
).setSubtitle(response.message);
card.setHeader(cardHeader);
return card.build();}
```

The requirement is: when a new sheet is added or removed the add-on has to be refreshed with the card in checksheetchange accordingly.

Even through the control comes to the function "checksheetchange", when a sheet is added or removed, there is no change in the card displayed in the add-on.

How can I refresh the add-on from the function "checksheetchange"?

Comment: Whenever you create a new trigger you should check to make that there isn't already a trigger defined for that function.  Multiple trigger function can be difficult to debug.

Comment: What I do is delete all existing triggers. But, the control is not passing from the trigger to the add-on. The cards are not refreshing.

Comment: Why delete all of the triggers when you don't have to.

Comment: Oh Ok. But, how do I refresh cards with a trigger?

Comment: What is this line supposed to do?`var response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText())`  response is not defined?

Comment: @Cooper In fact, the function can be as simple as: function checksheetchange(){
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
var cardHeader = CardService.newCardHeader();
cardHeader.setTitle(
  '<font color="#1257e0">File upload error!</font>'
);
card.setHeader(cardHeader);
return card.build();}

Comment: Well I'm just pointing out that you're declaring a variable and using the undeclared variable inside the assignment function.  So that doesn't make much sense.  If you going to post a lot of code please post it in your question so that it's easier to read.

Comment: [This may be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62594317/)