# Is there a way to add multiple actions to widget in Gmail apps script add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on Gmail add-on that allows to start new draft/reply using email template.
User can navigate to templates list and start new draft by clicking one of them ([Decorated text widget](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/decorated-text)).
I'm wondering is there a way to set the navigation in add-on after draft was started. I would like to close templates menu and get the user back to previous page.

Tried to combine actions on widget like:

```
templateCard
                .setComposeAction(
                  myComposeAction,
                  CardService.ComposedEmailType.STANDALONE_DRAFT)
                .setOnClickAction(
                  myNavigationAction
                )
```

But it doesn't work. Only compose action is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. Based on [Google's Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/decorated-text#setcomposeactionaction,-composedemailtype):

> A UI object can only have one of setOpenLink(openLink), setOnClickAction(action), setOnClickOpenLinkAction(action), setAuthorizationAction(action), or setComposeAction(action, composedEmailType) set.

You would need to add an additional UI element with the .setOnClickAction() method. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62596513) where a similar scenario was given. I'd highly recommend you to submit a feature request outlining the limitations and your current use case, maybe this could be updated in the future.

[Link to Google Workspace Add-ons Feature Requests](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=642720&template=1392206)